# JSF 2 Ajax requests fail on IE 9

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2, internet-explorer-9

I recently tried to test my JSF application on IE9 and discovered all Ajax requests to fail with a MalformedXML exception complaining about an undefined object when trying to access the removeChild attribute. I observed the problems both with MyFaces 2.0.5 and mojarra 2.1.1. Are there any known limitiations or prerequisites to support IE 9?

To reproduce the problem I nailed it down to a simple test case consisting of one ajax request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
    <f:view  contentType="text/html">
    <h:head>
        <h:outputScript name="jsf.js" library="javax.faces" target="head"/>    
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form id="#{testBean.idForm}">
                <h1>Test of IE9 Ajax</h1>
                <h:panelGroup id="#{testBean.idDiv}" layout="block">
                    Text: <h:outputText value="#{testBean.text}"/>
                    <br/>
                    <h:commandLink 
                        action="#{testBean.onAction}"
                        value="click me">
                        <f:ajax render="#{testBean.idDiv}"/>
                    </h:commandLink>
                </h:panelGroup>
            </h:form>
        </h:body>
    </f:view>
</html>
```

The bean is

```
package ietest;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class TestBean {
        private int clickCount;   
        private String idForm="testForm";
        private String idDiv="testDiv";

        public String getText(){
        String text = "you clicked " + clickCount +" times";
        System.out.println("Return text " + text);
        return text;
    }

    public String onAction(){
        System.out.println("onAction invoked");
        clickCount++;
        return "iebug";
    }

    public String getIdDiv() {
        return idDiv;
    }

    public String getIdForm() {
        return idForm;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Looks like Mojarra issue [JAVASERVERFACES-1981](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-1981).

Comment: This was it. To avoid changing JSF version I use a patched jsf.js which explicitly import. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks so much, it saved my day. Upgrade from 2.0.21 to 2.2.8 an it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

Cannot reproduce this problem using Mojarra 2.1.1 on Tomcat 7.0.12.

[image]

Your problem is caused by something else. I *suspect* it's in your real code an incorrect use of dynamic ids as you have with `#{testBean.idDiv}`. Try it with fixed ids (why would you ever make it dynamic?)

Further, the `<h:outputScript>` is entirely superfluous, this one is already by default included by JSF. Remove it. If it makes the problem bigger, then it is definitely caused by something else, e.g. a dirty classpath of different JSF versions mixed altogether.

Comment: yeah, I was wondering about those component identifiers. The id attribute accepts literals only (components won't resolve these expressions). Still, they seem to be resolved and coerced at tree creation time in Facelets. I haven't been able to find anything in the spec on the matter.

Comment: @McDowell: yes, this support is new in JSF2.

Comment: I am just facing the same issue but with Mojarra 2.0.2 and IE9. This must be the [Mojarra issue](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-1981) referenced in McDowells answer. The issue is fixed meanwhile for Mojarra 2.1. But how should I process with version 2.0.2?